# How to fuzzy match two lists in Python

Tags: python, matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have two lists: `ref_list` and `inp_list`. How can one make use of FuzzyWuzzy to match the input list from the reference list?

```
inp_list = pd.DataFrame(['ADAMS SEBASTIAN',  'HAIMBILI SEUN',  'MUTESI 
                          JOHN', 'SHEETEKELA MATT', 'MUTESI JOHN KUTALIKA', 
                          'ADAMS SEBASTIAN HAUSIKU', 'PETERS WILSON', 
                          'PETERS MARIO', 'SHEETEKELA  MATT NICKY'],
                          columns =['Names'])



ref_list = pd.DataFrame(['ADAMS SEBASTIAN HAUSIKU', 'HAIMBILI MIKE', 'HAIMBILI SEUN', 'MUTESI JOHN 
                         KUTALIKA', 'PETERS WILSON MARIO', 'SHEETEKELA  MATT NICKY MBILI'], columns = 
                        ['Names'])
```

After some research, I modified some codes I found on the internet. Problems with these codes - they work very well on small sample size. In my case the `inp_list` and `ref_list` are 29k and 18k respectively in length and it takes more than a day to run.

Below are the codes, first a helper function was defined.

```
def match_term(term, inp_list, min_score=0):
    # -1 score in case I don't get any matches
    max_score = -1
    
    # return empty for no match 
    max_name = ''
    
    # iterate over all names in the other
    for term2 in inp_list:
        # find the fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(term, term2)
    
        # checking if I am above my threshold and have a better score
        if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = term2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)


# list for dicts for easy dataframe creation
dict_list = []

#iterating over the sales file
for name in inp_list:
    #use the defined function above to find the best match, also set the threshold to a chosen #
    match = match_term(name, ref_list, 94)
    
    #new dict for storing data
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({'passenger_name': name})
    dict_.update({'match_name': match[0]})
    dict_.update({'score': match[1]})
    
    dict_list.append(dict_)
```

Where can these codes be improved to run smoothly and perhaps avoid evaluating items that have already been assessed?

Comment: Have you looked at https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact, that is where they explain the basic usage of fuzzywuzzy. There emphasis there is on the usage of the four ratios and how a single string or name can be matched to a list of strings or names.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to vectorized the operations instead of evaluate the scores in a loop.

Make a `df` where the firse col `ref` is `ref_list` and the second col `inp` is each name in `inp_list`. Then call `df.apply(lambda row:process.extractOne(row['inp'], row['ref']), axis=1)`. Finally you'll get the best match name and score in `ref_list` for each name in `inp_list`.

Comment: I am not too sure how to move forward

`df = pd.DataFrame({'ref': pd.Series(ref_list), 'inp': pd.Series(inp_list)})`

`df.apply(process.extractOne(row['inp'], row['ref']))`

**NameError: name 'row' is not defined**

Comment: Sorry there is a typo, please try again.

Comment: I think that we are getting closer. I have changed to the revised code and below is the first 5 items I am getting. Let me careful go through it again maybe there is something I am missing

`0   (A, 60)`
`1   (A, 60)`
`2   (A, 60)`
`3   (A, 60)`
`4   (A, 60)`

Answer (score 0):

The measures you are using are computationally demanding with a number of pairs of strings that high. Alternatively to `fuzzywuzzy`, you could try to use instead a library called [`string-grouper`](https://pypi.org/project/string-grouper/) which exploits a faster Tf-idf method and the cosine similarity measure to find similar words. As an example:

```
import random, string, time
import pandas as pd
from string_grouper import match_strings

alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
from_r, to_r = 0, len(alphabet)-1

random_strings_1 = ["".join(alphabet[random.randint(from_r, to_r)]
                            for i in range(6)) for j in range(5000)]
random_strings_2 = ["".join(alphabet[random.randint(from_r, to_r)]
                            for i in range(6)) for j in range(5000)]
                
series_1 = pd.Series(random_strings_1)
series_2 = pd.Series(random_strings_2)

t_1 = time.time()
matches = match_strings(series_1, series_2,
                        min_similarity=0.6)
t_2 = time.time()
print(t_2 - t_1)
print(matches)
```

It takes less than one second to do 25.000.000 comparisons! For a surely more useful test of the library look here: https://bergvca.github.io/2017/10/14/super-fast-string-matching.html where it is claimed that

> "Using this approach made it possible to search for near duplicates in
> a set of 663,000 company names in 42 minutes using only a dual-core
> laptop".

To tune your matching algorithm further look at the [**kwargs arguments](https://github.com/Bergvca/string_grouper#kwargs) you can give to the `match_strings` function above.